# How do I parse this piece of innerHTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I did this:

```
var blah = document.getElementById('id').getElementsByClassName('class')[0].innerHTML;
```

Now I have this in bar:

```
<a class="title" href="http://www.example.com/" tabindex="1">Some text goes here</a> <span class="domain">(<a href="/domain/foobar.co.uk/">foobar.co.uk</a>)</span>
```

I want to read the string "Some text goes here" from the HTML using JS (no jQuery). I don't have access to the site's HTML. I'm parsing a webpage to inject JS for a browser extension.

Will I just have to parse it as a string and find my text from between > and < or is there a way to parse innerHTML in JS?

Comment: so why are you not selecting the anchor?

Comment: "Now I have this in bar"  what bar? Does it have any spare beers?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('class')` this trys to find an element with an attribute `class="class"` did you mean `getElementsByClassName('title')`

Comment: Are you always going to be pulling text from an an anchor tag? If so, why not get it directly and access its `textContent`?

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm sorry. I meant blah. Or var.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm sorry. I hurriedly made the code simpler to read. The innerHTML was much more convoluted and most of the content didn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic HTML markup that I am assuming you have:

```
<div id="id">
    <div class="class">
        <a class="title" href="http://www.example.com/" tabindex="1">Some text goes here</a> <span class="domain">(<a href="/domain/foobar.co.uk/">foobar.co.uk</a>)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So select the anchor and read the text

```
var theAnchorText = document.getElementById('id').getElementsByClassName('class')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent;
```

if you need to support IE8

```
var theAnchor = document.getElementById('id').getElementsByClassName('class')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
var theAnchorText = theAnchor.textContent || theAnchor.innerText;
```

and if you are using a modern browser, [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) makes it a lot cleaner

```
var theAnchorText = document.querySelector("#id .class a").textContent;
```

Comment: Was answering with something similar and this popped up

Comment: where is the `id='id'` ??

Comment: @Khalid In the JavaScript part of the OP's question :p It's probably not a real ID, and the OP hasn't shown the containing HTML

Comment: @PatrickEvans Why would you assume that? The OP selected the parent element and wants part of the text of a child element.

Comment: Sorry, took _"Now I have this in bar:"_ meant something else and not that he misspelled `bar`, and had the string in his `blah` variable

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this two ways. A regexp or `textContent` on a temp DOM element:

```
var foo = "<b>bar</b>";

function regexpStrip(str) {
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}

function parseViaDOM(str) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = str;
  return el.textContent;
}

console.log(regexpStrip(foo)); // => "bar"
console.log(parseViaDOM(foo)); // => "bar"
```

Comment: Reg Exp with HTML NO NO NO! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @epascarello: wrong link. This is the right one to answer this kind of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/648265

Comment: Agreed, Regexp is bad in HTML. I was under the impression the sample string he gave above was all there was in which case a regexp strip would work. But for anything more regexp would be evil bad :imp:

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Ah, normally I google the right one, copied the url without looking :)